# Symfony3 Guard Authentication - prevent InteractiveLoginEvent from being dispatched for API requests

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the new Guard authentication for authenticating API requests. Diving into the Guard code, I see that it triggers a `InteractiveLoginEvent` once the authentication was successful.
My application listens for that event to track user logins, so I don't necessarily want it to be triggered for API requests.

I was wondering whether there was a way to bypass the event being dispatched in Guard for API authentication?
Or did I misunderstand the purpose of the `InteractiveLoginEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can (or necessarily should) stop the `InteractiveLoginEvent` from firing, but what about modifying your login listener to ignore API requests? If all your API endpoints are mounted under the `/api` URL root, you can do something like:

```php
public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    // Don't process login event for API requests
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if (strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/api') === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // … rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up doing something similar, but using the authenticationToken to get the User and inspect that user to detect whether it was a normal login or API request. Don't you think that InteractiveLoginEvent shouldn't be triggered though..? If Guard is meant to be flexible enough to allow for API authentication, you should be able to stop the event from being triggered.... Or would an authenticated API request count as an InteractiveLoginEvent?

Comment: @SamuelCloete I think the event should fire regardless (it's an important hook), but I found it odd that Guard fires it on every request. I thought that with regular `form_login` it only fires on the actual login, not subsequent requests, but the author claims that's the intended behaviour: https://twitter.com/weaverryan/status/720318076399566848